# Positioning background image in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{
\tikz
\node[opacity=0.060]
{\includegraphics[scale=.85]{La Salle Logo.png}};}
```

Comment: I would like to center the background image but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You show no minimal example that can be compiled, so it is not totally clear what you want.

Maybe the options `anchor=center` and `shift=(current page.center)` do what you want. For `current page` to work, you also have to add options `remember picture` and `overlay`. So your code might be amended to

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{
\tikz[
   remember picture,
   overlay,
   shift = {(current page.center)},
   ]

\node[
   anchor = center,
   opacity=0.060
   ]
   {\includegraphics[scale=.85]{La Salle Logo.png}};

} % \usebackgroundtemplate
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend simpler solution, use `trim`.
This is used to trim picture, it needs values for each side (left, bottom, right, top). Here I've used *negative* value for *left* to manually add space. You'd need to try some values to get satisfactory effect - it is manual centering.
I've also set height of picture to `paperheight`, adjust it if you want.

It is for `beamer` with `aspectratio=169`.

```
{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, trim=-5cm 0cm 0cm 0cm, clip]{MY-IMAGE}}
}

\begin{frame}{My frame title}

FRAME CONTENTS

\end{frame}
```